# Syntax error when including "or" in a string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, irony

I am currently using Irony as part of my search process(not my choice and I don't have a say :P) and there is an issue with using the combination of letters "or" followed by a space and another word, I.E "Orbit Gum" however if you search things like "orbit" or simply "or" on its own it seems to work positively fine.

The error that occurs is

```
Syntax error near 'gum' in the full-text search condition 'orbit gum'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Syntax error near 'gum' in the full-text search condition 'orbit gum'.
```

The code being used to generate this part of it is

```
        //Union with the full text search
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fTextSearch))
            {
                sql.AppendLine("UNION");
                sql.AppendLine(commonClause);
                sql.AppendLine(string.Format("AND CONTAINS(nt.text, '{0}', LANGUAGE 'English')", fTextSearch));
            }
```

The actual query that is causing the issue as far as I can see is this line:

```
AND CONTAINS(nt.text, 'orbit gum', LANGUAGE 'English')
```

Comment: [Maybe you need it in double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435119/syntax-error-near-of-in-the-full-text-search-condition-control-of)

Comment: Oh goodness. Why don't you put the query in a single string instead of a dozen `AppendLine` clauses.

Comment: in a "normal" sql query I'd use `AND nt.text LIKE '%orbit gum%'` in the last line

Comment: It's done in such a horrible way due to how many issues Irony has relating SQL injection, I'm not 100% on how the search works as I haven't actually written majority of this code, only the parts that fix problem characters and thank you Vendetta, that looks like it could be a sensible soloution for the issue, I will try it and report back how it goes.

Comment: @HelloWorld You may want to consider editing your other question and closing this one as it's effectively the same question - apologies if it isn't but I think both of them effectively boil down to the CONTAINS clause.

Comment: They are and they aren't, as silly as that sounds but they are two questions in a sense as the other was a mess and had problems with two errors so I am trying to separate them to make them clearer.

Comment: You may want to edit this question so it becomes something like; "my sql query fails when I append the statement "CONTAINS(column, 'orbit gum') but succeeds when I do CONTAINS(column, 'gum'). The exact error I get is... - this will then remove all of the extraneous code and detail your exact issue. If you want, I could edit this for you, and, if you are not happy, we could just roll it back. However, you may also wish to consider closing it as it is an exact duplicate of @V4Vendetta's link

Comment: That'd be nice if you could, thanks! Helps clear out the problem better, I'm terrible at finding issues (not a very experienced programmer :P)

Comment: Perhaps we should agree that if V4Vendettas provided link works, you could close this question, and if it doesn't we'll do the edit.

Comment: Yeah, I'll give it a go and keep you posted.

Comment: The fix didn't work, thanks for the post though!

Comment: I have made some amends myself to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this myself using a simple bit of Regex, it turns out that you are able to simply add quotation marks onto the beginning and end of the string and it stops it throwing the error.

```
 fTextSearch = Regex.Replace(fTextSearch, ".*(or|and|etc).*", "\"$&\"");
```